# SugarCRM currency field max value

Tags: sugarcrm

There is min and max value parameter for Integer field in SugarCRM but for some reason the Currency field has no these parameters.

I need to limit the user in entered value in currency field with the standard alert.

Not found any solution yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution. It quite easy, don't know why SugarCRM not implemented it in standard field definition for this type.

1. Create the file - `custom/modules/MODULENAME/customValidate.js`, assume that the currency field name is `amount_c`:

   ```
   $(document).ready(function(){
       min = 0;
       max = 100;
       formname = 'EditView';
       addToValidate(formname, 'amount_c', 'currency', true, 'Limited Amount');
       validate[formname][validate[formname].length-1][jstypeIndex] = 'range';
       validate[formname][validate[formname].length-1][minIndex] = min;
       validate[formname][validate[formname].length-1][maxIndex] = max;
   });
   ```
2. Load this JS in your editview by adding this line: `{sugar_getscript file="custom/modules/MODULENAME/customValidate.js"}` into `javascript` array inside of these files: `custom/modules/MODULENAME/metadata/editviewdefs.php` and `custom/modules/MODULENAME/metadata/quickcreatedefs.php`.

   (below as it is in my file):

   ```
   ...
   ),
   'javascript' => '{sugar_getscript file="custom/modules/dm_bonif/validateAmount.js"}',
   'useTabs' => false,
   ...
   ```
3. Run Quick Repair and it should work.